# I want to create a doctor appointment application, which would be the best approach to set his working schedule?

Tags: database

Each doctor should have it´s own working schedule, Monday, Tuesday, ..., and the working hours, time slots of half an hour.

I´m kind of lost on how design the tables and related them.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to do a little more and then when you get stuck we can provide some guidance and opinions. We cannot design the database for you.

Comment: Hi Vincent, thank you for your answer, I´ve been trying but I´m lost on how to set up the doctor schedule.

A doctor has one schedule
A doctor can work up to 7 days and let´s say 12 hours a day

Answer (score 1):

The standard design could be like :

```
Doctors(id,name,specialization,...)
Patients(id,name,birthdate,.....)
Calendar(doc_id,pat_id,startDate,endDate,subject,....)
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to save the schedule of each doctor, so I can match their availability when a user(patient) select a date and an hour.

Comment: Calendar table contains the schedule of each doctor and you can easily  match availability by date and hour.